# Integrals in Reverse

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm asked what solid this integral represents(the integral is used to obtain the volume of a solid, we are given this).

[image]

I see that since we have the $ 2\pi$, this is probably a volume obtained by using cylindrical shells. Now, I think that $(3 -y)$ could be radius or height, and that $(1-y^2)$ could be height or radius. I'm not really sure what to do with this information, anyone know how I could derive the solid?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_integration

Comment: Radius will be always be linear for a regular axis rotation.

Comment: @vadim123 I know how to do Shell Integration, I'm having trouble working in reverse. I'm wondering how to obtain what solid this integral represents.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The axis of rotation is $y=3$

Comment: Okay which means I could say the radius is represented by $(3-y)$ and the height is given by $(1-y^2)$?